# html code gets deleted from wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i'm developing a gateway processor for a wordpress plugin and i'm stuck.
although the plugin has the functionality i want, i'm facing a very wierd problem.
i declare a textarea which is meant to take some html code in the backend and echo it on the frontend. Some of the html code gets stripped out when i click save button, this code includes  and  tags among others.
i declare the code like:

```
 $this->fields['description'] = array(   
'type'        => 'wp_textarea'
, 'default'     => ''
, 'placeholder' => ''
, 'title'       => __('Description', 'booking')
, 'description' => __( 't page.' ,'booking')
, 'description_tag' => ''
, 'group'       => 'general'
, 'tr_class'    => ''
, 'rows'        => 30
, 'show_in_2_cols' => true
, 'css'         => 'width:100%'                                 
, 'teeny'             => true
, 'show_visual_tabs'  => true
, 'default_editor' => 'tinymce'                     
, 'drag_drop_upload'  => false 
);
```

i have also tried changing `default_editor` to `html` and `type` to `textarea` but with the same results.
could someone please help?
i have burned my mind on this one.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if I inserted `<script>alert("Haha, goofed you!")</script>` in your editor if it didn't strip tags.

Comment: i guess i'd be goofed when i opened the page hahahaha. unfortunately i only get alert("Haha, goofed you!") as the <script> tags are stripped out :(

Comment: Real unfortunate that it decides to strip tags if you could just run all kinds of JavaScript in there, no? ;)

Comment: <script> tags are not the only ones that are stripped <pre> <i> <center> are some more